# DBPedia: all population fields?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to extract all entities in DBPedia that have a population. However, I have found that there are different field names for population depending on the entity. For instance, `http://dbpedia.org/page/Boston` has the field `populationTotal` while `http://dbpedia.org/page/Alaska` has the field `2010pop`. Is there a complete list of the population fields that I can query for?

Comment: I don't think that there is a list. Some properties are in the DBpedia ontology, others are just infobox mappings. Different properties are used because of different classes resp. infoxbox templates in Wikipedia. You can try to use SPARQL and query for all properties that match some pattern in the name.

Comment: Something like `select ?p {
?p a rdf:Property
filter(regex(str(?p), "pop"))
}` - indeed, it depends on the regex pattern, but in the end you have to walk though a list and decide which is correct or not.

Comment: For the properties of the `/ontology/` namespace, you could also try to use the range as an additional filter: `select ?p ?range {
?p a rdf:Property
filter(regex(str(?p), "pop"))
optional {?p rdfs:range ?range}
}`

Comment: Perfect! I don't mind filtering the list manually. Thanks! Is there an easy way to then take that list of properties and find all entities that have at least one of those properties?

Comment: "easy" for me is SPARQL, something like `SELECT DISTINCT ?s {
    VALUES ?p {dbo:populationTotal dbp:2010pop}
    ?s ?p ?o
    }` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Solution via @AKSW above: query for all properties that start with "pop" and have a specified range.

`SELECT ?p ?range {
    ?p a rdf:Property 
    FILTER(regex(str(?p), "pop")) 
    OPTIONAL {?p rdfs:range ?range} 
    }`

Comment: Note that this query finds all properties that *include* (don't necessarily begin with, end with, or have in the middle) the case-sensitive substring "pop", and it definitely finds a few that are questionably "population".  Also, the `rdfs:range` specification is optional -- so lacking it doesn't exclude a property from the list. When you're manually reviewing the output, it can be helpful to include something like `ORDER BY ?range ?p`.